# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined in NextJS 12

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I am trying to build a spotify-clone using NextJS 12 and tailwind css template.

I used this command to create the project : `npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss spotify-2`.

The project was created susscessfully but as I ran `npm run dev` after doing a `cd spotify-2`, I am getting the following error :

```
> @ dev /home/aishik-ubuntu/MEGAsync/Programming On Ubuntu/My Projects/NextJS Projects/spotify-2
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
(node:14702) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at /home/aishik-ubuntu/MEGAsync/Programming On Ubuntu/My Projects/NextJS Projects/spotify-2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:67:19
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/aishik-ubuntu/MEGAsync/Programming On Ubuntu/My Projects/NextJS Projects/spotify-2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:900:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/aishik-ubuntu/MEGAsync/Programming On Ubuntu/My Projects/NextJS Projects/spotify-2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:6:20)
(node:14702) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14702) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at /home/aishik-ubuntu/MEGAsync/Programming On Ubuntu/My Projects/NextJS Projects/spotify-2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:67:19
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/aishik-ubuntu/MEGAsync/Programming On Ubuntu/My Projects/NextJS Projects/spotify-2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:900:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/aishik-ubuntu/MEGAsync/Programming On Ubuntu/My Projects/NextJS Projects/spotify-2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:6:20)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/aishik-ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2021-11-26T18_33_22_412Z-debug.log
```

What should I do now?

Comment: I was also running node on a old version. Once node update to latest version, above works fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same error but with the typescript template

```
npx create-next-app@latest --typescript
```

I was running a very old node version 10. I upgraded to version 16 LTS and then it ran without error. You can check your version with this command:

```
node -v
```

System requirements on the site state node version 12.22.0.
https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started#system-requirements

Comment: saved me so much time, ty

Comment: Succeeded with : nvm use 16