# Why I'm not able to start next.js in WSL2

Tags: npm, next.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows 10 Pro (Version 21H2 - Build 19044.1387) and WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) and
Docker Desktop 4.2.0 (70708). In WSL2 I've installed node v10.19.0 / npm v6.14.4

Normally I work with ddev for PHP Development without any problems. Now I wanted to take a look at next.js. I installed next.js as described on their documentation https://nextjs.org/docs). But when I run **npm run dev** I'm getting the following output:

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
(node:1511) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at /home/tmode1960/workspace/learn-next/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:67:19
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tmode1960/workspace/learn-next/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:900:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tmode1960/workspace/learn-next/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:6:20)
(node:1511) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1511) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
error - Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
Error: Not supported
    at Object.loadConfig [as default] (/home/tmode1960/workspace/learn-next/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/config.js:399:74)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@ dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tmode1960/.npm/_logs/2021-11-29T08_44_26_964Z-debug.log
```

I don't know what to do to see the output on http://localhost:3000

Comment: Can you show me the code!

Comment: What code do you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined in NextJS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70128771/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-referenceerror-textencoder-is-not-defined-in)? Upgrade your Node.js version to 12 or higher.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think my Node.js was a little bit outdated. After upgrade it to a higher version it works.