# Getting code ELIFECYCLE error when trying to run Nextjs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js

I have created the new Nextjs project and when I run the npm run dev got following error

```
> @ dev /home/dell/Documents/project_Clone/cloned-project
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
(node:29535) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at /home/dell/Documents/project_Clone/cloned-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:67:19
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dell/Documents/project_Clone/cloned-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:900:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dell/Documents/project_Clone/cloned-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:6:20)
(node:29535) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:29535) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at /home/dell/Documents/project_Clone/cloned-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:67:19
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dell/Documents/project_Clone/cloned-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:900:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dell/Documents/project_Clone/cloned-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:6:20)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dell/.npm/_logs/2021-12-12T15_45_05_610Z-debug.log
```

As per given solutions I also run npm cache clean, deleted node-modules and npm i bt getting same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined in NextJS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70128771/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-referenceerror-textencoder-is-not-defined-in)? You most likely need to upgrade to a supported Node.js version.