# Setting up Next.js on ubuntu problem. code ELIFECYCLE errno 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to setup next.js on a fresh install of ubuntu. This is my first time setting up next.js and also I am fairly new to ubuntu. I would appreciate any help you guys can point me to. When I get to the part to run "npm run dev" I get the following error output:

```
npm run dev

 @ dev /home/christopher/dev/projects/react-projects/tutorial/nextjs-blog
 next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
(node:34150) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at /home/christopher/dev/projects/react-projects/tutorial/nextjs-blog/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:67:19
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/christopher/dev/projects/react-projects/tutorial/nextjs-blog/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:900:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/christopher/dev/projects/react-projects/tutorial/nextjs-blog/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:6:20)
(node:34150) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:34150) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at /home/christopher/dev/projects/react-projects/tutorial/nextjs-blog/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:67:19
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/christopher/dev/projects/react-projects/tutorial/nextjs-blog/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.development.server.js:900:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/christopher/dev/projects/react-projects/tutorial/nextjs-blog/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:6:20)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/christopher/.npm/_logs/2022-01-23T21_57_02_558Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What versions of Node and NPM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined in NextJS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70128771/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-referenceerror-textencoder-is-not-defined-in)

Comment: What’s your Nodejs version? You must install at least the version 12.22.0.

Comment: node version 17.4.0, npm 8.3.1

Comment: It looks like I fixed it by removing node and npm and then reinstalling using ```curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs ```  instead of what I did before which was sudo apt-get install node and sudo apt-get install npm